# How to enable and use wifi adapters with ubuntu server on pi 3b+?

Tags: wifi, usb

I got the following pi with ubuntu server installed

```
OS: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS aarch64
Host: Raspberry Pi 3 Model B Rev 1.2
Kernel: 5.15.0-1024-raspi
Uptime: 3 mins
Packages: 832 (dpkg), 4 (snap)
Shell: bash 5.1.16 
Terminal: /dev/pts/0 
CPU: BCM2835 (4) @ 800MHz 
Memory: 172MiB / 905MiB
```

and I have three wifi adapters that i would like to use any of

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0cf3:9271 Qualcomm Atheros Communications AR9271 802.11n
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2001:3319 D-Link Corp. DWA-131 Wireless N Nano Adapter (Rev. E1) [Realtek RTL8192EU]
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 148f:761a Ralink Technology, Corp. MT7610U ("Archer T2U" 2.4G+5G WLAN Adapter
```

they are detected as usb devices but not detected in `ifconfig` or `iwconfig`, I came across [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1417968/cant-get-wifi-adapter-mt7601u-to-work-on-ubuntu-server-22-04-for-raspberry-pi-4) answer that states extra modules should be installed, so I did use the command `sudo apt-get install linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-1011-raspi` and installed them but  still not able to get the interfaces to work

I know that the interfaces are relatively old but they work with other debian based distros on this pi

searching for firmware package results in the following

```
pi@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt list |grep ^firmware

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

firmware-ast/jammy 20140808-4 all
firmware-ath9k-htc/jammy 1.4.0-106-gc583009+dfsg1-1ubuntu1 all
firmware-b43-installer/jammy 1:019-7build2 all
firmware-b43legacy-installer/jammy 1:019-7build2 all
firmware-microbit-micropython-doc/jammy 1.0.1-2 all
firmware-microbit-micropython/jammy 1.0.1-2 all
firmware-sof-signed/jammy-updates,now 2.0-1ubuntu4 all [installed,automatic]
firmware-tomu/jammy 2.0~rc7-2 all
```

Comment: You have provided no information. ifconfig or iwconfig are pointless until you configure networking. For a start list `lshw -class network` and `ls /sys/class/net/`. Last time I used ubuntu server it used `systemd-networkd` and didn't support wireless networking although the desktop image used Network Manager.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following

```
firmware-realtek
firmware-linux-nonfree
firmware-linux-free
firmware-linux
```

There are other wifi specific modules.  Generally named firmware-*

```
sudo apt list |grep ^firmware

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

firmware-amd-graphics/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-ath9k-htc/stable,stable 1.4.0-106-gc583009+dfsg1-1 all
firmware-atheros/stable,stable,now 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all [installed]
firmware-b43-installer/stable,stable 1:019-7 all
firmware-b43legacy-installer/stable,stable 1:019-7 all
firmware-bnx2/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-bnx2x/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-brcm80211/stable,stable,now 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all [installed]
firmware-cavium/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-intel-sound/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-intelwimax/stable,stable 1:20210315-3+rpt7 all
firmware-ipw2x00/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-ivtv/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-iwlwifi/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-libertas/stable,stable,now 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all [installed]
firmware-linux-free/stable,stable 20200122-1 all
firmware-linux-nonfree/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-linux/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-microbit-micropython-dl/stable,stable 1.2.4+dfsg-8 all
firmware-microbit-micropython-doc/stable,stable 1.0.1-2 all
firmware-microbit-micropython/stable,stable 1.0.1-2 all
firmware-misc-nonfree/stable,stable,now 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all [installed]
firmware-myricom/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-netronome/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-netxen/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-qcom-media/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-qcom-soc/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-qlogic/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-realtek/stable,stable,now 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all [installed]
firmware-samsung/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-siano/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-sof-signed/stable,stable 1.7-1 all
firmware-ti-connectivity/stable,stable 1:20221012-1~bpo11+1+rpt1 all
firmware-tomu/stable,stable 2.0~rc7-2 all
firmware-zd1211/stable,stable 1:1.5-7 all
```

Comment: I did use your command but i don't think the resulting packages are related to wireless interfaces

Answer (score 1):

Servers often do not have wireless support (and Ubuntu Server is no exception), certainly not wireless clients and do not include the tools required.

There seems little point in adding WiFi (unless you want the server to act as an Access Point). (Even less point in installing 3!)

If you REALLY want WiFi install `Network Manager` - which is the normal Ubuntu networking tool.

It is possible to activate WiFi with `systemd-networkd` but this requires wpa_supplicant and is more complex.